# When I attempt to execute my recursive function with odd numbers ,i have a kern problem

Tags: python, function, recursion

There is a problem with odd numbers.
When I run the function on even numbers, the code works.

```
    #recursive demo function1
    #Even nums
    def evenNum(num):
        if num % 2 != 0:
            print("enter a even number")
        if num == 2:
            return num
        else:
            return evenNum(num-2)        
    evenNum(5)
```

```
 output : Canceled future for execute_request message before replies were done
```

Comment: print out the num and you'll see what the issue it. Remember integers can be negative as well as positive.

Comment: You forgot to return after that print.

Comment: return print("enter a even number")

Answer (score 3):

The second `if` should be changed to `elif`. When number is odd it prints `"Enter a even number"` and then compares it to 2. As it is different, it calls the function again.

Here is fixed code

```py
    def evenNum(num):
        if num % 2 != 0:
            print("enter a even number")
        elif num == 2:
            return num
        else:
            return evenNum(num-2)        
    evenNum(5)
```

Btw. make sure the number is greater than 0.

Comment: I forgot in my code elif statement. Simple error but instructive.Thanks for your solution

Answer (score 0):

```
#recursive function1
#positive Even nums
def evenNum(num):
        print(num)
        if num % 2 != 0:
            return print("enter an even number")
        elif num == 2:
            pass
        else:
            return  evenNum(abs(num)-2)        
evenNum(5)
```

> Thank you for your valuable advice.
> I learned some things about return and kern error.